# Ctrl + Home and Ctrl + End working in text editor pane but not in pdf previsualizer pane for TeXMaker and Kile

Tags: shortcut-keys, latex

Just installed TeXMaker, Kile, TeXStudio and TeXworks.

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- Computer: Laptop (DELL)

The "go to end of file" keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> works in the editor pane for all three editors. But in the previsualization pane, in only seems to work on TeXStudio and TeXworks.

Precisions: Since this is a laptop, I actually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>. I fist make the test in the editor pane. It works well. Then I give the pane focus by clicking on it. But then on pressing the key combination nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong (like, not using the right shortcut) or should I report a bug to the authors of Kile and to the authors of TeXMaker ?

Edit: I added TeXworks above. Note that Kile has not been updated for years.

Comment: If the key otherwise works, then you probably should report an issue to the developpers, because it is up to the application to implement a key or not.

Comment: Thanks. Btw I just realized Kile has not been updated for years. I've just tested TeXworks, which... works with that respect

Comment: I reported a while ago to TeXMaker dev. Still not working as of today.